# Adding Typescript interfaces for deeply nested object returned by API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, typescript2.0, object-type

I'm new to Typescript and trying to add types to a simple app. I'm stuck on an error with a deeply nested object.

```
export default function AnimalAdoptionCosts() {
  const [currencyQuote, setCurrencyQuote] = useState({});
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

    const fetchAdoptionRates = async (userInput: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/v1/adoptionRate?animal=${userInput}`
    );
    console.log(response);
    const body = await response.json();
    if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
    setCurrencyQuote(body);
  };


  const handleSubmit = async (userInput: string) => {
    await fetchExchangeRates();
    const costToAdopt = currencyQuote?.data.quote.USD.price;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(userInput)}>
        <label htmlFor="animal">Enter an animal type</label>
        <input
          value={userInput}
          id="userinput"
          placeholder="ex: Pomeranian"
          onChange={(event) => setUserInput(event.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
       {costToAdopt}
      </form>
    </>
```

The Typescript error is: `[1] Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.  TS2339` for this line: `const costToAdopt = currencyQuote?.data.quote.USD.price;`

I get that this is because useState sets the default as an empty object, but it feels weird to do

```
interface CurrencyQuote {
 data: {
    quote:  {
       USD:   {
         price: number
       }
    }
}
```

is this what I should be doing? I found this [example playground to work off of](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4FgBQyRywAJgFzIgCuGARtANwHHIDOwAXhJTfUwQC%20BUJFiIUAUQAecDAAcANijyFiIOT3ZgooAObM1RYJjaVVrVgG0A1hACelNjv0BdSuggYWxQYeH4BABucFDIAPZ0AFaUMnJKKAC8OD5EGhhaAESQzpkANKkkpuaFrJlwmSVGlqxklACMBdU1RBzcDQAMpb5NLciZdJUpzS11yABMvX3EbVoAzAAs3UQBrAGCQA), but then I would make 4 different interfaces, which seems overcomplicated.

Also if you're a TS whiz, I'd love help figuring out how to type out the other important info in my function. Thank you!

Comment: The first thing I'm noticing is there doesn't seem to be a reason for `adoptionRates` to be stateful, unless you use it somewhere else?

Comment: @Nick good point, I realized in simplifying my code I messed up some variable naming, it is now `currencyQuote` and once costToAdopt is set, I want to display the result

Comment: Even given this variable change, I think you're right that it doesn't need to be stateful, I can probably just return the `costToAdopt` in the fetchAdoptionRates fn

Comment: That all being said, I still _do_ think it's generally worthwhile to write the full typing for your returned data type. That gives you the full benefit of TS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need `costToAdopt`, I'd recommend just storing that value alone in your `useState` as a number. That makes the typing a lot easier and you can avoid all the nesting.

```
const [costToAdopt, setCostToAdopt] = useState<number>(0);

// ...

const fetchAdoptionRates = async (userInput: string) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:5000/v1/adoptionRate?animal=${userInput}`
  );
  console.log(response);
  const body = await response.json();
  if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
  setCostToAdopt(body?.data?.quote?.USD?.price || 0);
};

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot and simplified some things. I went ahead and added similar typings to all my useState functions. 
  const [cryptos, setCryptos] = useState<Object>({});
  const [conversionRateToUSD, setConversionRateToUSD] = useState<number>(0);
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState<string>("");

Is there more I should do in terms of interfaces?

Comment: Instead of type `Object` for `cryptos`, I'd create an interface with the keys you will use in cryptos and use that so you can access the properties without type errors.